# How to give PREFIX=<Dir> in luarocks install <rockname> command?

Tags: lua, makefile, luarocks

I am trying to install turbo using the [this](https://turbo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/get_started.html) guide. I want to install turbo in some dirctory other than /usr/local. The make file from the turbo source code on [git repo](https://github.com/kernelsauce/turbo/blob/master/Makefile) has a variable called PREFIX, whose default value is /usr/local.
When issue following command how can I pass the value for PREFIX.

```
$ luarocks install turbo
```

Also, the guide shows other way to install turbo by cloning the repo and providing PREFIX to make command, but I just want know if there is any way to do this using luarocks install.

### Excerpt from the turbo guid

> You can also install Turbo use the included Makefile in the project source:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/kernelsauce/turbo.git
$ cd turbo && make install
```

> You can provide a PREFIX argument to the make which will install Turbo in a specified directory.

Comment: http://leafo.net/guides/customizing-the-luarocks-tree.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--tree` flag with LuaRocks to install a module to a custom directory. Example: `luarocks install --tree lib lpeg`